# Media querys are not working in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have created two media queries in an attempt for a responsive page but the bottom media query is not working.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .header-my-account-btn {
        position: absolute;
        top:-64px;
        right: -240px;
    }
    .header-cart-withlist-links-container-inner {
        position: absolute;
        top:-5px;
        right: -35px;
    }
    .tf-f-cart-icon {
        visibility: hidden
    }
}
;

@media screen and (min-width: 350px) {
    .header-my-account-btn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 44px;
        right: 240px;
    }
    .header-cart-withlist-links-container-inner {
        position: absolute;
        top:-5px;
        right: -35px;
    }
}
;
```

I am using wordpress css editor to edit the css

Comment: Describe `not working`. Please provide minimal reproducible example to be able to help you. And you don't need `;` after media queries

Comment: The css doesnt do anything on the page

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess since the theme you happen to be using will affect things greatly. It can be overriding your styles.

One observation.

I'm surprised you see anything for this. It says to only work when the browser is exactly 1920px. Shouldn't do anything for any other dimension.
`@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 1920px)`

Second.
Semicolons after media queries aren't needed or proper. The one after the first media query might be causing the 2nd to break. Especially if your theme has any type of css optimizer installed.

Try removing the semicolons after the media queries.

Answer (score -1):

Try using !important with each css property, there might be a possibility that you are overriding some already defined property

Comment: `!important` should be _very_ last thing to do, because then there will be _overwrite !important with more important rule_. Simply adding one additional selector in most cases helps much more than nightmare of `!important`

Comment: So what if its the last thing ...if this work than what else we need ...i am just saying to try if this works